# Proving that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are the smooth functions around the point $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

> I want to show that the expressions: $x^2 + u -xu - v = 0$ and $x^3 +y - \sin (xv) - u = 0$ are defining the smooth
>   functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ around the point $(0,0)$. These
>   functions satisfy $u(0,0)=0$ and $v(0,0)=0$

I haven't seen any example like this yet and I don't know what to do. If those functions are smooth, they have to be differentiable. But should I join these two equations and express $u$ or $v$ or I don't know. Any hint please, how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: look up Implicit function theorem!

Comment: Do you have any good materials, not sure where to look, this example just interested me

Comment: So i would derivate these two expression with the respect to $u$ and $v$ and then plug (0,0)?

Comment: A nice (elementary) exposition of the implicit function theorem can be found in Apostol's *Calculus II*.

Comment: @Leif Without implicit theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating wrt $x $ and $y $, we get

$$2x+u_x-u-xu_x-v_x=0$$
$$u_y-xu_y-v_y=0$$
$$3x^2-(v+xv_x)\cos(xv)-u_x=0$$
$$1-xv_y\cos(xv )-u_y=0$$

with $x=0$ and $y=0$, we find

$$u_x=v_x $$
$$u_y=v_y $$
$$v=-u_x $$
$$u_y=1$$

hence
$$u_y=v_y=1$$
or
$u_y\ne 0$ and $v_y\ne 0$

$u $ and $v $ are smooth around $(0,0) $.